# React Virtualized position of list item

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm using React Virtualized in a similar setup like the snippet below. There are a couple of items that are rendered using a `CellMeasurer`. The last item indicates that more items will be loaded and is not rendered normally. This item has the wrong position/style and the wrong height associated with it. How can I fix this?

If you want to play with it, here is a Plunkr: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/TrKdNu4FfNsXqERPVnYo?p=preview

```js
var List = ReactVirtualized.List;
var CellMeasurer = ReactVirtualized.CellMeasurer;
var CellMeasurerCache = ReactVirtualized.CellMeasurerCache;

var cache = new CellMeasurerCache({
  fixedWidth: true,
  minHeight: 50
});

// List data as an array of strings
var namesList = [
  'Brian Vaughn',
  'Bob Smith',
  'Someone Else',
  'I hate making up names for the sake of names.'
  // And so on...
];

var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      list: namesList
    };
  },
  render: function() {
    return <List
    className='List'
    width={300}
    height={300}
    rowCount={this.state.list.length + 1}
    rowHeight={cache.rowHeight}
    deferredMeasurementCache={cache}
    list={this.state.list}
    rowRenderer={
      ({ index, isScrolling, key, parent, style }) => {
        var item = this.state.list[index];
        let result;
        if (!item) {
          console.log(index);
          result =
            <div className='Row'
          style={style}
          key={key}
            >Loading!!!
          </div>; }
        else
          result = <CellMeasurer
        cache={cache}
        columnIndex={0}
        key={key}
        style={style}
        rowIndex={index}
        parent={parent}>
          {

              <div
            className='Row'
            key={key}
            style={style}
              >
              {this.state.list[index]}
            </div>
          }
        </CellMeasurer>;
        return result;
      }}/>;
  }
});

// Render your list
ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

```css
.List {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.Row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react/dist/react-with-addons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-virtualized/dist/umd/react-virtualized.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/react-virtualized/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="example">
      <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your code... -->
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CellMeasurer` wasn't intended for use with only certain rows in this way. From an external POV I understand why it looks like it should just work though.

When `Grid` renders a cell- if it thinks `CellMeasurer` is being used- then it [positions the cell at top:0, left:0](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/eb50a1569c8a59ec3d296145b636dff4b24ccae8/source/Grid/defaultCellRangeRenderer.js#L66-L75) to give it space within the `Grid`/`List` to expand. (The size of its container constrains its size, even though it's absolutely positioned. I'm not sure why this is to be honest.)

So in your case, `Grid` sees the last row hasn't been measured, think it's supposed to be, and positions it at 0,0.

The simplest solution for now would be to just wrap that row in `CellMeasurer` too.

Comment: OK, thanks. I was trying this because you suggested it on Slack to save one DOM measure, but I can certainly live with this!